# Issues w advanced virtualenv configurations on Mac for scikit-learn and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, virtualenv, virtualenv-commands

In short: **I am using virtualenv to manage a large amount of requirements but I am concerned that I have conflicting versions of major packages on my Mac.**

I have installed both scikit-learn and matplotlib via pip, but my PyCharm won’t acknowledge they exist.

Then I allowed PyCharm (and I tried dozens of times) to “Install requirements” but the error kept coming up when installing matplotlib:

> - The following required packages can not be built:
>
>   ```
>                   * freetype
>   ```

I’ve tried installing freetype in any ways but it seems to already be here.  How do I get passed that error?

From other postings, I learned there is a very noble attempt to get these and many other essential Scientific Python packages installed using the Scipy Superpack for Homebrew

https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack

I believe this installed correctly but Pycharm still doesn't see it.

***Could I be pointing to the original (presumably failed) pip installs when I want to point to the Scipy Superpack??  How do I update my virtualenv to see these packages?***

I also found the Anaconda version of Python (which should include matplotlib AND scikit-learn?) and my virtualenv was not pointed to that python executable, but updating that did not help.  **Do I need to update “which” matplotlib or other packages to point to as well?**

I have literally been at this for days and I would throughly appreciate some help.  So much in the scientific community of Python requires matplotlib and my research looks like it could really benefit from scikit-learn so any help is greatly appreciated.  I realize there are dozens of other posts related to this but the solutions have not resolved my issue.  Thank you for any help you can give!

### Additional requested info:

python -c "import sys; print sys.path" gave:

> ['',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.15.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python27.zip',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/Extras/lib/python',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>   '/[$HOME]/.virtualenvs/JS_dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: What python interpreter and PYTHONPATH is your pycharm looking at? https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python.html

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I see the problem.  You're using system python (on macs you get these issues a lot if you try and use system python, commonly people will use an alternative python), but homebrew installs to `/usr/local`, so if you do a

```
brew install pythonX.X
```

then when you create your virtualenv environment (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-virtual-environment.html) select the python out of `/usr/local/bin` instead and check the inherit global site-packages.  That will probably take care of your issues.

Comment: THIS IS GREAT!   But to clarify, I should call homebrew BEFORE I open and start a new virtualenv?  and then can I just pip install from a freeze list?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't even need to do that.  If you "inherit global site-packages" or setup `--extra-search-dir` (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference.html#cmdoption--extra-search-dir) you won't need to reinstall them. They'll use the existing installations then you only need to `pip install` the package specific to that project and packages you expect to use frequently can be installed in `/usr/local/...`

Comment: Oh dear so I am doing something wrong already:  Rs-Mac-mini:~ rpanos$ brew install python2.7
Error: No available formula for python2.7 
==> Searching formulae...
==> Searching taps...
Rs-Mac-mini:~ rpanos$ brew install python
Warning: python-2.7.10_2 already installed

Comment: Sounds like Python is already installed. You just need to select that installation in pycharm for your virtualenv.